# Cytoscape.js - not adding all "ele" at startup

Tags: cytoscape.js

*Situation:*
I have a graph with 500 nodes (say 1000 edges), with a root.

*Goal:*
I want the user able to progress in the graph, by cliking on nodes, showing the edges and new nodes around.

*Way I do for now:*
I first load all elements in memory (the entire json), then use ele.remove() for each nodes/edges. And just keep visible the root and around.

*Question 1)*
Is there any solution to choose the element to display at startup.(and not removing them later)

*Question 3)*
Removing the element does not free memory. Is there a solution to use memory for only elements that are not removed ?

*Question 2)*
Are there a smarter/better approach to do the trick ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/visibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using classes with visibility-related properties, as mentioned, would work.

You can also [animate elements](http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/animation) and [animate the viewport](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/animation) to highlight parts of the graph.